# Cannot publish my Web Forms Project (ASP.NET) from my Mac

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio, web-deployment, visual-studio-mac

I need to publish my project to my FTP server, but I can't find how to publish it in Visual Studio for Mac. Does anyone know where is the "Publish" button?

Comment: Hello, and welcome. [Based on the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/web-app-deployment?view=vsmac-2019), it appears that **Visual Studio for Mac 2019** only supports publishing to an [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/publish-app-svc?view=vsmac-2019) or a [folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/publish-folder?view=vsmac-2019), likely because of a lack of `msdeploy` on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in terminal:

`dotnet publish`

and then, get the publish folder that was created in the process and upload to your host via FTP (inside the `wwwroot` folder).

Comment: Will that work for an ASP.NET Web Forms project that's not written in .NET Core?

Comment: no , this command just work for .NET Core
[based on the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli)

Comment: That's what I thought. Keep in mind that this question is specific to ASP.NET Web Forms.